# В чем разница в произношении гусь гус и гюсь?

Tags: произношение

Дифтонговый "с" смягчен "у", но этого не достаточно, чтобы оправдать звук в "гюсь". В чем причина?

Comment: Что такое "дифтонговый с"? Какой звук нужно оправдать?

Comment: `гусь` — hard g, soft s, `гус` — hard g, hard s, `гюсь` — soft g, soft s.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос о смягчении "г", то гласные и, е, ё, ю, я смягчают **предыдущий** согласный.

> уголок --уголёк, глас – гляссе, гусь – гюйс.

Правило, однако, не распространяется на шипящие ж, ш, ц , которые остаются твердыми

> жили, жёлтый, шили

Звуки "ч, щ, й" всегда мягкие.

> щи, число.

Существуют исключения : например, "е" не всегда смягчает предыдущий согласный звук,особенно в иностранных словах:

> стресс, декольте, кашне.

В слове "гусь" звук "с" смягчен мягким знаком, следующим за ним.

Answer (score 0):

Гус - is very close in pronunciation to "goose" except for the duration of "u" sound. In "гус", it's pronounced way shorter.

Гусь - compared to "гус", has different sound in the end. "Ь" letter is not pronounced. Yet, it makes the consonant it stays after soft. This letter in Russian is called "мягкий знак"/"soft sign". However, it can do nothing in such words as "ночь", "тишь", "мышь" because they belong to the 3rd declesion.

Гюсь - sounds very similar to "гусь", but lettet "ю" makes the consonant it stands after soft. (Note: I also pronounce it as something between "и" and "у").